# Exception when creating Spring Boot Otka resource server

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security-oauth2

I'm running to an issue when creating a Spring Boot resource server using Otka for token authorization.

I'm following the tutorial located here: https://developer.okta.com/quickstart/#/vue/java/spring

And here's a minimum sample project that has the same issue: https://github.com/AdrianLeeElder/jwt_issue

When starting up this project, I get the following exception:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jwtDecoder' defined in class path resource [com/okta/spring/boot/oauth/OktaOAuth2ResourceServerAutoConfig.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.security.oauth2.jwt.JwtDecoder]: Factory method 'jwtDecoder' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: issuer cannot be null
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:627) ~[spring-beans-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:607) ~[spring-beans-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1321) ~[spring-beans-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1160) ~[spring-beans-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555) ~[spring-beans-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:515) ~[spring-beans-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320) ~[spring-beans-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318) ~[spring-beans-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:843) ~[spring-beans-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:877) ~[spring-context-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:549) ~[spring-context-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:142) ~[spring-boot-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:775) [spring-boot-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) [spring-boot-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:316) [spring-boot-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1260) [spring-boot-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1248) [spring-boot-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at com.adrian.Application.main(Application.java:14) [classes/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.security.oauth2.jwt.JwtDecoder]: Factory method 'jwtDecoder' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: issuer cannot be null
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185) ~[spring-beans-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:622) ~[spring-beans-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    ... 19 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: issuer cannot be null
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.notNull(Assert.java:198) ~[spring-core-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.jwt.JwtIssuerValidator.<init>(JwtIssuerValidator.java:45) ~[spring-security-oauth2-jose-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at com.okta.spring.boot.oauth.OktaOAuth2ResourceServerAutoConfig.jwtDecoder(OktaOAuth2ResourceServerAutoConfig.java:69) ~[okta-spring-security-oauth2-1.0.0.jar:1.0.0]
    at com.okta.spring.boot.oauth.OktaOAuth2ResourceServerAutoConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$329b08dd.CGLIB$jwtDecoder$0(<generated>) ~[okta-spring-security-oauth2-1.0.0.jar:1.0.0]
    at com.okta.spring.boot.oauth.OktaOAuth2ResourceServerAutoConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$329b08dd$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$30450659.invoke(<generated>) ~[okta-spring-security-oauth2-1.0.0.jar:1.0.0]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:244) ~[spring-core-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:363) ~[spring-context-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at com.okta.spring.boot.oauth.OktaOAuth2ResourceServerAutoConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$329b08dd.jwtDecoder(<generated>) ~[okta-spring-security-oauth2-1.0.0.jar:1.0.0]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154) ~[spring-beans-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    ... 20 common frames omitted
```

Answer (score 0):

For some reason Spring does not pick up on the properties defined in `application.properties`. These properties can be passed as a run parameter and it works fine.